# Happy 2023 to all

Tags: mathematics

It can be shown that (apart from 0 and 1) 2023 is the sole number that equals the sum of its digits multiplied twice by the sum of the squares of its digits. Indeed:

2023 = (2+0+2+3) x (2^2 + 0^2 + 2^2 + 3^2)^2

Are most other numbers *n* **happier** (the corresponding product is greater than *n*) or ****sadder**** (the corresponding product is less than *n*) than *n*?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking if the corresponding product for a number $n$ is greater than or less than $n$?

Comment: @DanielMathias You are right!

Comment: Should have checked my source (Twitter). Freddy Barrera has found other happy numbers: 2400, 52215, 616627, 938600, and 1648656.

Answer (score 7):

All numbers greater than some threshold are

> sadder than the number.  Intuitively the sum of digits is roughly the logarithm of the number and the sum of squares of the digits squared is a power of the logarithm of the number, so the calculation is roughly a power of the logarithm of the number, which grows more slowly than the number itself.

To make a bound on the threshold

> Let $n$ have $k$ digits.  The right side is at most $9k\cdot (81k)^2=3^{10}k^3$  The left side is at least $10^{k-1}$.  For $k=9$ the left is $100,000,000$ and the right is $43,046,721$ so all numbers of at least $9$ digits are sadder than the number.